# Using Server Side Constants in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have a web page that calls back to my web service. Occasionally, a 404 may occur. I am trying to detect that using the structure:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/myService/myAction",
  contentType: "application/json",
  success: action_Succeeded,
  error: action_Failed
});

function action_Succeeded() {
  // Do stuff
}

var v = 0;
function action_Failed(p1, p2, p3) {
  if (p1.status != 200) {
    if (ServerSideObject.COUNT == v) {
      // Do Stuff
    }
  }
}
```

I have a class on the server with a publicly visible int called COUNT; How do I plug that value in where "ServerSideObject.Property" exists? I thought I could use `@ServerSideObject.Property` but that doesn't seem to work. How do I plug this value in? For reference, ServerSideObject looks like the following:

```
public class ServerSideObject 
{
  public const int COUNT = 3;
}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: elaborate on "but that doesn't seem to work"

Comment: ServerSideObject class is not static how can ServerSideObject.COUNT work it should give you an Null reference error.

Comment: @Nikshep, because its a `const`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using razor in view within javascript block **does work**, but editor shows some errors caused by javascript editor not supporting razor. Ignore them and try what it does in browser.